# How to correctly customize the drop-down menu created by ul-li tags?

Tags: html, css, frontend, scss-mixins

[image: ul li dropdown menu]

[image: after]

I created a drop-down menu using tags `ul` and `li`. This works, but I want that when opening the menu, it does not shift the blocks below like on screen. So, this is my css:

```
#select-ul {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0.1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-top: 0;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  float: none;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fc-oyl31mRI  See this video with some javascript it will look great but it will be quite complicated.

Comment: Actually, I use VueJS, so JS won't be a problem, but this is pure html + scss

Comment: Just give it a ```z-index: 1;``` with ```position: absolute;``` it did work for me sure with you too.

Comment: Btw, `position: absolute;` works, but dropdown menu doesn't scale by size of window. I mean, size of window `Preferences` changes with size of browser's window, but menu is static. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your css a bit like

**OLD CSS**

```css
#select-ul {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0.1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-top: 0;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  float: none;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

**NEW CSS**

```css
#select-ul {
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; /* you can change but must give width */
  max-height: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; /* 0.1px doesn't work */
  border-top: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden scroll;
}

#select-ul.active {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

And a bit JavaScript convert it in `vue` as you are using it.

```js
const dropdown = document.querySelector('#select-ul');

dropdown.addEventListener('click', () => {
  dropdown.classList.add('active'); // you can also use toggle
});

// additionally 
dropdown.addEventListener('blur', () => {
  dropdown.classList.remove('active');
});
```

Lemme know if this work! TBH I am not getting what scaling issue you are talking about. *elaborate it some more.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I can't get it, but where do I have to add this JS code? I mean, I have `scss` file with styles and `vue` (`<template>`, `<script>`, `<style>`) file. And that's it.

Comment: Actually, nevermind, I have added `v-if` to the blocks below. So, when I open `ul-li`, you won't see that `Currency` and button `Save preferences` :D