# How to make synchronous scaling of elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, frontend

I've created `ul`-`li` drop-down menu. I used those tags because I added icons of flags (you'll see on pics). So, when I change size of window `ul`-element is scaled, and it's okay. But I also want to make scalable `li`-list.

So, this is how it looks:
[image]

`ul`-`li` list has to be like `select`-`option` drop-down menu. To be 'one' element.

[image]

As you can see window 'Preferences' is scalable with settings inside, but not `li`-element.

Here is `scss`:

```
#select-li {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-bottom: 0.1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
#select-ul {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0.1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-top: 0;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

For any case, here is `Vue` code:

```
<ul v-if="showSortBy" id="select-ul">
   <li
     id="select-li"
     @click="defCountry = country; showSortBy = !showSortBy"
     v-for="country in countries"
     :key="country.key"
    >
     <img :src="country.src" width="18" height="18" alt="">
     {{country.val}}
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try adding `position:relative;` to `ul`'s parent element

Comment: Well, actually, I've tried, and it works. But, take a look on second pic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68602128/how-to-correctly-customize-the-drop-down-menu-created-by-ul-li-tags. It's my previous post. And I don't know how to make that `ul` element not to move other elements

Comment: Can you provide the parent and siblings for the `ul` pls :)

Comment: Could you please just write it as an answer or give example?

Comment: would you create an online example, I think it can make more people give you a solution https://codesandbox.io/s/vue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did to make it work:

```
.select-ul-country {
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0.1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-top: 0;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden scroll;
  .select-li-country {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-bottom: 0.1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    img {
      width: 18px;
      height: 18px;
    }
  }
}
```